# Camel case code generation with swagger

Tags: swagger

I am trying to generate python client from a swagger yaml file. It works fine, except that the response models are all snake cased(words sep. by underscores) instead of camel cased. I provided the camel cased versions like this:

`definitions:
    serviceResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        serviceResponseInternal: 
           type: object`

The generated code has a ServiceResponse object which has an internal field service_response_internal. I would like it to respect the convention and just have serviceResponseInternal instead of underscored seperated names. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Swagger Codegen, you can customize the `toVarName` in the Python code generator:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/PythonClientCodegen.java#L180

Can you elaborate on why you don't want to go with snake case for model properties (which should conform to [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))?

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. Reason to keep the camel cased names is to use consistent naming on the backend and the frontend. It allows searching for a field name in the entire code base and see where is it used. This helps to rediscover the code base months/years later before making changes and also useful for on-boarding new developers.